# Set Navlink Href Property with Enum

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages, razorengine, blazor-server-side

In blazor application i am trying to set href property of NavLink with the help of Enum

Example :

```
 <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/Products/ProductType.All" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
 </NavLink>
```

Here ProductType is an Enum but in browser it make url like

> ProductList/ProductTypes.All

instead of

> ProductList/1

where 1 is for All

If i put @ symbol here

```
href="/ProductList/@ProductTypes.All"
```

than it say component attribute does not support complex content

what is the workaround here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your enum is

```cs
public enum ProductTypes{
   All = 1
}
```

so try to use this

```html
href="@($"/ProductList/{(int)ProductTypes.All}")"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Great , Its working . Please add enum keyword in your first line of answer between public ProductTypes so it will not confuse someone  , also dont forgot to upvote this question , Promot Blazor